# Long March 3C/E specification

Tags: long-march

From what I can see, it looks like the [Long March 3C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_March_3C) is pretty much a [Long March 3B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_March_3B) with two strap-on boosters instead of four.

The Long March 3B/E is actually a Long March 3B with a bit higher boosters and first stage.
The same with Long March 3C/E - the boosters and first stage have same specifications as Long March 3B/E

The question is what is the height, mass and payload capacity to LEO

[This link](https://nextspaceflight.com/launches/details/2105) says about Long March 3C/E

- Rocket Height: 55.64 m - instead of 56.3 m as Long March 3B/E
- Payload to LEO: 8,000 kg - which is equal with Long March 3C
- Strap-ons: 4 - which is hard to believe, because then it will be identical with Long March 3B/E
- Liftoff Thrust: 5,923 kN

And [this link](https://nextspaceflight.com/launches/details/5165) says about Long March 3C

- Rocket Height: 54.84 m
- Payload to LEO: 8,000 kg
- Strap-ons: 2
- Liftoff Thrust: 5,923 kN - which can not be, because it is the same as Long March 3B/E, which has 4 strap-on boosters instead of 2

The real data that I estimate for Long March 3C/E is the following:

- Rocket Height: 56.3 m - same as Long March 3B/E
- Payload to LEO: less than 8,000 kg of the Long March 3C
- Strap-ons boosters: 2
- Liftoff Thrust: 4,442 kN
- Liftoff mass (t): 345 (= Long March 3C) + 33 (difference between Long March 3B/E - Long March 3B)

Can anyone help with more accurate data?

Comment: Got in contact with peeps at Next Spaceflight; yeah thrust of LM-3C is an error, it should be lower. Honestly if you want to inform/discuss with them the errors in LV directly just join the discord at https://discord.com/invite/v6wt4pr